# Setting proxy using CFNetwork works in the simulator not on device

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, cfnetwork

I use the following Xamarin.iOS code to set up a proxy.

```
var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
System.IntPtr myHandle = Dlfcn.dlopen("/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork", 0);
var keyHost = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(myHandle, "kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost");
var keyPort = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(myHandle, "kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort");
Dlfcn.dlclose(myHandle);
NSDictionary proxyDict = new NSDictionary(keyHost, "<my-host-value>", keyPort, "<my-port-value>");
configuration.ConnectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;
```

It works in the simulator but not on device (iPhone and iPad). How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I think I found the solution.
Path to the dynamic library (first parameter in Dlfcn.dlopen) should be:

> "/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork"

or you can use class Constants:

> Constants.CFNetworkLibrary